# 25%/70ms dropouts in fuel pressure in Cummins ISL 07

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, pressure, rich

[image: 1000RPM idle]

The first picture is low idle, the second is high idle. With the exception of the spikes, the high idle looks more normal to me.

Anyone know what this signifies? I just replaced the PRV which was dribbling, and am thinking metering valve next under the assumption that the spikes are compensation opposite of an overshoot that might be due to the metering valve glitching out.

[image: a]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!